# Get Laravel public path in external js file

Tags: laravel, routes, path, public-folders

I have blade file named `index-game.blade.php`. And in one line of it, a line that reaches a js file under laravel `public` folder.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('game/')}}/js/CPreloader.js"></script>
```

So far so good.

Also inside `CPreloader.js`, I have lines like this.

```
s_oSpriteLibrary.addSprite("bg_menu","./sprites/bg_menu.jpg");
s_oSpriteLibrary.addSprite("progress_bar","./sprites/progress_bar.png");
```

At this stage, I get the following error in the console of my browser's devtools screen:

```
bg_menu.jpg:1          GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/games/sprites/bg_menu.jpg 404 (Not Found)
progress_bar.png:1     GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/games/sprites/progress_bar.png 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the link where I called "index-game.blade.php" => `http://127.0.0.1:8000/games/slot1` (Let's pay attention to the `games` word here)

It works if i change my javascript file to

```
s_oSpriteLibrary.addSprite("bg_menu","../game/sprites/bg_menu.jpg");
s_oSpriteLibrary.addSprite("progress_bar","../game/sprites/progress_bar.png");
```

Because the correct link is this instead

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/games/sprites/bg_menu.jpg // wrong
http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/sprites/bg_menu.jpg // true
```

I don't want to change the paths in all my javascript files. Because this is a game and there are as many pictures as possible. How do I correctly identify the laravel public folder in my external js files.

Comment: As far as I understood, you want to rename the **games** dir to **game**. So, what is the problem?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI games tell you that there is more than one game,  The game, on the other hand, tells that it is just a game. an understandable structure when we think like a tree.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for that: https://github.com/tighten/ziggy

Some copy/paste from docs:

Install Ziggy into your Laravel app with

```
composer require tightenco/ziggy
```

Generate javascript route file:

```
php artisan ziggy:generate
```

Import in js file and use:

```
// app.js

import route from 'ziggy';
import { Ziggy } from './ziggy';

// ...

route('home', undefined, undefined, Ziggy);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it, if it works , I give reputation for you.